# How do I target setInterval to a specific html tag

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

For example I want this setInterval function to be targeted on a specific tab

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
    var counter = 10;
    setInterval( function(){ 

          printf (counter);
          counter--;
          if (counter === 0) {
        console.log("Yay its functional!!"); }
        clearInterval(newYearCountdown);

    }, 5000 );
});
```

This is the HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs admintabs">
                <li class=""><a href="">Announcements</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Messages(X)</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Requests</a></li>
            </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I want it to be targeted on X in the messages. 
I hope someone can help me on this :(

Comment: A couple of observations, first in order to `clearInterval`, you need to set a variable equal to `setInterval` (it should be pretty easy to modify your code).  Second, I might suggest putting X in a span with an ID for easy identification

Comment: What do you mean by "targeting a specific" with a `setInterval` function?

Answer (score 1):

In principle you want to update an element in your DOM programatically.

To achieve this, you have to make that object *identifyable*, e.g. via class attribute.

In your HTML, a possible solution could be:

```
<li><a href="">Messages(<span class="result">X</span>)</a></li>
```

You may have a look at the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1q97he63/).

I would encourage you to have a look at `Templating` in javascript, because this is what you usually want.

There are libraries like

- [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/)
- [mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/)

Which help you achieve, what you want.

Of course, there are more elaborate and more recent tools, to do this; but at the moment, simple templating seems to suit your needs.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for your response. I will look into it now.